# How does this product over finite primes represents density of certain natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

Let $p_{i}$ be the $i^{th}$ prime. I read that the product

$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \big( 1 - \frac{1}{p_{i}} \big)$ represents the density of primes that are not divisible by any of the $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots , p_{n}$.

I realized that density of natural numbers divisible by any one of the $p_{i}$ is $\frac{1}{p_{i}}$; by any two of them is $\frac{1}{p_{i}p_{j}}$ with $i \neq j$ and so on. Note that each of these sets are infinite.

It appears that inclusion exclusion here is done on density level to obtain that the set of natural numbers divisible by at least of these primes $p_{i}$ has density

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_{i}} - \sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{p_{i}p_{j}} + ... + (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{p_{1}p_{2} \cdots p_{n}} $

and hence the set of natural numbers not divisible by any of these $p_{i}$ has density

$1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_{i}} - \sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{p_{i}p_{j}} + ... + (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{p_{1}p_{2} \cdots p_{n}} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \big( 1 - \frac{1}{p_{i}} \big) $

However,

1. Is such exclusion-inclusion allowed in density arguments? If yes, why?
2. If yes, what conditions do the sets $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{k}$ need to satisfy before I can start using analogous argument on these sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use inclusion-exclusion like this.  Just intersect all your sets with $[1,N]$ and use ordinary inclusion-exclusion to count them.  Then divide by $N$ and take the limit as $N\to\infty$.  More generally, this would work for any finite collection of sets $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ such that every intersection of a subcollection of them has a natural density.

In this case, though, you can just count directly instead of using inclusion-exclusion.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, there are exactly $\prod_{i=1}^n(p_i-1)$ residues mod $\prod_{i=1}^np_i$ that are not divisible by any $p_i$, since you just need the residue mod each $p_i$ to be nonzero and these can be chosen independently.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean in the first paragraph. I didn't think of that at all. I have accepted your answer. I still wanted to know a little about your second paragraph, if you were kind enough to explain it in a couple of lines or something. 
Are you using probability or something?

Comment: I'm not sure what part of it you don't understand.  The Chinese remainder theorem says that the canonical map $\mathbb{Z}/(\prod p_i)\to\prod\mathbb{Z}/(p_i)$ is a bijection, and I'm just counting the elements of $\prod\mathbb{Z}/(p_i)$ that are nonzero on every coordinate.

Comment: I understand the CRT part. How does counting in the way you have said (through this bijection) give us the density of the required set. Can you justify and/or relate to the original definition or is it just some ad-hoc argument?

Comment: Well, how do you know that the multiples of $p_i$ have density $\frac{1}{p_i}$?  It's really almost the exact same argument.  Split the natural numbers into blocks of $\prod p_i$, and $\prod (p_i-1)$ of them in each block are not divisible by any $p_i$.  Then if you take the first $N$ natural numbers, it will consist of a bunch of blocks plus some remainder, and the remainder becomes negligible as $N$ gets large.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes perfect sense to me. I appreciate your kind explanation.

Comment: What was the reason that this downvote?